# How to display the comments_template with a shortcode, in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, shortcode

I managed to display the comment_form with a shortcode (while removing it from the default location) using the code below:

```
`add_shortcode( 'wpse_comment_form', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        comment_form();
        print(  '<style>.no-comments { display: none; }</style>' );
        add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );
```

Code suggested by birgire in this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177289/26350

For more clarity, here is where I want to get: I need to display both the comments form and the comments list through shortcodes and in different locations. I managed to mimic the same code above to display the comments_template (and later editing the comments.php to remove the comment_form from it, since what I really need to display is the comments list) but the comments list displays 2x, one in the shortcode location and also at the bottom of the post (default location). I tried to use the same code to display the wp_list_comments independently but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the `[wpse_comments_template]` shortcode before this part in your theme:

```
<?php
    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
        comments_template( '', true );
?>
```

then it's attempting to use:

```
add_shortcode( 'wpse_comments_template', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        comments_template();
        add_filter( 'comments_open',         '__return_false'             );
        add_filter( 'get_comments_number',   '__return_zero'              );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );
```

but this might interfere with comment related stuff that comes later, for example in the sidebar.

So it would be more accurate to use:

```
/**     
 * Display the comment template with the [wpse_comments_template] 
 * shortcode on singular pages. 
 *
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28644134/2078474
 */
 add_shortcode( 'wpse_comments_template', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
 {
    if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        comments_template();
        add_filter( 'comments_open',       'wpse_comments_open'   );
        add_filter( 'get_comments_number', 'wpse_comments_number' );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );

function wpse_comments_open( $open )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return false;
}

function wpse_comments_number( $open )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return 0;
}
```

and you wouldn't have to remove any code from your theme.

I tested this on the Twenty Fifteen theme and it seemed to work as expected.

Comment: The "more accurate" way works here too, with Virality theme. But it is not giving me the results I need. 1) the comments_template displays the comments but also the comment_form below it (not on the bottom of the page; that part worked well), and I need the comments by themselves. 2) The [wpse_comment_form] is not displaying the form in the same page where I placed it. But it works on a different page where I use it as a way to submit content.

I need the

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to reach there. I believe I need to go back to codecademy for a while. So, for the moment, I'm thinking of going back to the strategy of using the shortcode functions you provided here, @birgire and removing the comment_form call from the comments_template (comments.php). I started another topic/question on if there are disadvantages between removing the functions calls or filtering them off through the functions.php file. No replies yet.

Comment: `add_filter( 'comments_open',       'wpse_comments_open'   );`

I removed this filter so that the shortcode to display the comment_form can work on the same page (so it seems to be the cause), and so I can still use the functions above while removing the comment_form from comments.php

Answer (score 1):

If you do not provide an array of comments wo wp_list_comments, then it expects to find that a query has already been done (i.e. in the loop).

If you want to display comments for a post independent of the loop, you can use something like:

```
    $comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $id ) );
    wp_list_comments( array( 'per_page' => how many to show ), $comments);
```

So to put it in a shortcode you would do something like (not tested):

```
add_shortcode( 'wpse_comment_list', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    if( isset($atts['id']) && post_type_supports( $atts['id'], 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        $comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $atts['id'] ) );
        wp_list_comments( array( 'per_page' => how many to show ), $comments);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );
```

and you would invoke it with `[wpse_comment_list id="33"]` (or whatever the id is).

Comment: Where would I fit the code you provided? In the shortcode function? I need it to be as a shortcode so it can be placed in a predefined section of the posts..

Comment: I shortcode-displayed things where I needed them and removed the calls to the functions in the files where I didn't need them, cuz I don't know how to filter them in the shortcode function. If someone can tell me if this method is less advisable or maybe even harmfull to the site's functioning, I'm willing to dig more into a better solution.
Glad that you came back to detail your suggestion. It makes it a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to arrive at the result that I needed but partly through deleting on my child-theme the parts that I couldn't remove through code.
I mimicked the code used to shortcode-display the comment_form (above in the question) to shortcode-display the comments_template (here below). It displayed it where I needed but it didn't remove it's "ghost" from the bottom of the post like the previous code did for the comment_form. So I copied single.php to my child-theme and deleted all this:

```
<?php
`// If comments are open or we have at least one, load up
    the comment template
    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
    comments_template( '', true );
?>
```

It worked. Not sure it's the best way though and I'm curious about it. I won't need comments at the bottom of posts anymore; my comment form is a different form now and has different locations too, in case that is the only issue.

Here is the code I used to shortcode-display the comments_template. I needed it to display only the comments and not the form, so I removed the comments_form call from the comments.php in my child-theme.

```
add_shortcode( 'wpse_comments_template', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    if( is_singular() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        comments_template();
        print(  '<style>#comments-title { display: none; }</style>' );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}, 10, 2 );
```